# How to fetch a serial number from a mysql table using Sequelize in nodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a mysql Query:-

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 serial_number,rule FROM pledges,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a;
```

This gives me a serial number along with the rule from the table.

How can I do that in Sequelize?

This is the query I wrote in the model which gives me id and rule:-

```
Pledge.getPledgeList = function(lang_code='EN') {
        return this.findAll({
            attributes:['id','rule'],
            where: {
                status:'a',
                deleted_at:null
            },
            include:[
                { association: 'local', where: {lang_code:lang_code} ,required: false},
            ]
        })
    }
```

Comment: you can use `attribute` to get specific data from table

Comment: if you want only id you can remove `rule` from `attribute`